# Reducing number of failed attempts in wget

Tags: bash, network-programming, wget

I have a simple script which uses wget in a loop until it succeeds. It eventually succeeds but it fails many times before it does so since the server it is trying to contact is down for a while. How can I reduce the number of "Connection refused" messages I am seeing in my output? I've tried using the `--waitretry` and `--wait` flags in `wget` to reduce the number of wget attempts but I still see many "Connection refused" attempts.

This is what my wget command looks like:

```
while :; do wget -T 30 -nc --wait=30 http://193.155.44.23 && break; done
```

And this is what I am seeing in my output:

```
--2021-07-19 17:52:05--  http://193.155.44.23/
Connecting to 193.155.44.23:80... failed: Connection refused.
--2021-07-19 17:52:05--  http://193.155.44.23/
Connecting to 193.155.44.23:80... failed: Connection refused.
--2021-07-19 17:52:05--  http://193.155.44.23/
Connecting to 193.155.44.23:80... failed: Connection refused.
--2021-07-19 17:52:05--  http://193.155.44.23/
Connecting to 193.155.44.23:80... failed: Connection refused.
--2021-07-19 17:52:05--  http://193.155.44.23/
Connecting to 193.155.44.23:80... failed: Connection refused.
--2021-07-19 17:52:05--  http://193.155.44.23/
Connecting to 193.155.44.23:80... failed: Connection refused.


(repeated many many times)
```

Comment: In order to reduce the number of "Connection refused" attempts we first need to understand _why_ they are happening... If they are happening because of a load on the server you may reduce them by either: scaling up more instances to serve your requests. or by increasing the wait between attempts.

Comment: The "connection refused" messages are happening because the server that it's trying to connect to is still "coming online". I just need to figure out a way to tell wget to wait more time between attempts I think

Comment: You can check the response and if it's "Connection refused" sleep a little longer than the normal "wait".

Comment: wget's `--waitretry` uses linear backoff. A common technique to minimise attempts is "[exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)". cf. [Retry](https://github.com/joshdk/retry)